# Complementary of #include <list> in C

Tags: c, list, sdl, paint

I'm trying to write a paint program in C for a school project. I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/drawing-lines-with-sdl2/), but it's in C++. I would then like to know if there is  a complementary of these lines of code:

```
#include <list>

std::list<Line> lines;
```

Comment: Not really. If you want to use linked lists in C, you need to write them yourself, although there are some libraries available.

Comment: No C doesn't have any standard data-structures or algorithms like C++ does.

Comment: Is there any way I can reach the same result as he does, without them?

Comment: Yes, you could use an array of `Line` structs, and just handle it how you would handle a typical array in C. If you're not new to C, this would be trivially easy. If you don't know how to do that, then you should be using much simpler tutorials before working up to this.

Comment: Ok, I can create a Struct Line,with the 4 "variable":x1,x2,y1,y2...but how would I store them if I have more than one line?Using the struct am I not going to have a single variable for a single line? And even if I would make an array of type Line, how can I know the lenght of the array if I don't know how many lines the user is going to draw?(I'm making a program using the SDL library)

Comment: @Stef_Supertramp upper limit is often known, especially for school projects. Otherwise you can allocate memory for required size at runtime with e.g. `malloc`/`realloc`, but it is highly unlikely you'll need that now.